# Python script for listing instances based on custom tags values passed during script execution

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, instances

I was trying out executing a python script in following way python script.py -env  - role  to fetch instances on specified environment and role values . Here is my script :

```
   import argparse
   import boto.ec2

   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '<xxxxxx>'
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '<xxxxx>'
   ec2conn = boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,         AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

   env = ''
   role = ''

   def get_ec2_instances():
    regions = ['us-east-1','us-west-1','us-west-2','eu-west-1','sa-east-1',
                'ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','ap-northeast-1']
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('env', help='tag:environment');
    parser.add_argument('role', help='tag:role');
    args = parser.parse_args()
    global env
    global role
    env = args.env
    role = args.role

   reservations = ec2conn.get_all_instances(filters={"tag:environment" :    "env","tag:role" : "role"})
  #reservations = ec2conn.get_all_instances()
  inst = [i for r in reservations for i in r.instances]
  for i in inst:
      print  "%s" % (i.tags['Name'])

   if  __name__ =='__get_ec2_instances__':get_ec2_instances()
```

Its throwing no error and no result..

Comment: `inst` list is probably empty...

Comment: And you have an indentation error, so the last `if` statement is not executed.

Comment: Fixed indentation error still its not working

Comment: retructure your code,  move argparse out of the function near the name part. And use boto3 !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is typical cargo-cult coding that you don't understand what are you copying , especially the argparse part, the **name** part, even the for next part. Also boto is deprecated! boto is deprecated! boto is deprecated! Use boto3 .

```
import argparse
import boto3

def get_ec2_instances(Env,Role):
    ec2 = boto3.client("ec2")
    reservations = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=
            [{
              "Name": "tag:environment",
              "Values" : [Env],
             },{
              "Name": "tag:role",
              "Values" : [Role]
             }])
    # following for diagnostic purposes
    # reservations = ec2.describe_instances()
    for reservation in reservations["Reservations"] :
        for instance in reservation["Instances"]:
            print "instance {} : Name:{} ".format(instance["InstanceId"], instance["Tags"][0]['Value'])


if  __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('env', default="environment", help='value for tag:environment');
    parser.add_argument('role', default="role", help='value for tag:role');
    args = parser.parse_args()

    get_ec2_isntance(args.env, args.role )
```

[filters is one of the poorly documented boto3 "magic"](http://sysadminandnetworking.blogspot.de/2013/12/aws-ec2-cli-filter-by-tag-name-and-value.html)

Comment: Still getting error  "Invalid type for parameter Filters, value: {'tag:role': 'es', 'tag:environment': 'qa'}, type: <type 'dict'>, valid types: <type 'list'>, <type 'tuple'>"